# How to extend PHP RuntimeException

Tags: php, runtimeexception

How can you extend PHP's *RuntimeException* class so you don't have to throw *RuntimeException* for every runtime exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending PHP's RuntimeException class is easy, as you don't have to implement any methods. For example, see this sample program:

```
class DomHtmlLoadException extends RuntimeException {}
throw new DomHtmlLoadException("cannot load /tmp/lockss-manifest.html");
echo "done BUT NO EXCEPTION!.\n";
```

Running this sample program yields a **DomHtmlLoadException** with the message "cannot load /tmp/lockss-manifest.html".